# The relevant error-causing widget was TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I recently added **Firebase** to my flutter project and got this error while trying to run it on an iOS Emulator[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import
```

'package:flutter_auth/components/text_field_container.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/constants.dart';

```
class RoundedPasswordField extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  const RoundedPasswordField({
    Key key,
    this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFieldContainer(
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: true,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        cursorColor: kPrimaryColor,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Password",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.lock,
            color: kPrimaryColor,
          ),
          suffixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.visibility,
            color: kPrimaryColor,
          ),
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wrap with material or add scaffold as parent on Build, does it solve the issue?

Comment: could you type the corrected part of code and send? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Add the code snippet of your widgets, then I will be able to check and be sure of myself.

Comment: I added the code above, please check now.

Comment: Also need to check the parent of this widget. i believe, the main page missing `Scaffold`, or need to be wrapped with material

Answer (score 0):

wrap the TextFieldContainer with material widget